# single instance of cron - kill old execution before starting new one

Tags: cron, kill-process, single-instance

The requirement is to run a cron on an hourly/daily basis.

But sometimes, the cron takes too long to complete before the subsequent execution.

So, when the subsequent execution starts, it shouldn't run 2 parallel jobs.

Instead, it is supposed to kill the already executing job & start a new one.

I tried the following but nothing worked.

1. pkill & run my script in cron - [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/517368/320709), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34058442/820410) & [this](https://askubuntu.com/q/1319097/191666)
2. `pgrep` & `kill` instead of `pkill` in above solution - a one-liner bash using `&&` & `;`
3. [run-one](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/kinetic/en/man1/run-one.1.html) & `run-this-one` also in it.

What's the best way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

`timeout`

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/timeout 59 /home/script.sh
```

The above cron runs every minute but the execution terminates after 59 seconds(if it has not finished).